# AWS Cognito User Authentication in C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I've been struggling to get AWS Cognito User Authorisation to work in Unity 2017.

There is a limitation with the Unity SDK, as per this request:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248872

I have tried a few different approches, and the closest I have got is with the code here:
https://gist.github.com/dbeattie71/44ea3a13145f185d303e620c299ab1c5

However when I call LoginUser with all the details setup, then I get this stack:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException (System.ExceptionArgument argument) (at <c95265f74fdf4905bfb0d5a4b652216c>:0)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].FindEntry (TKey key) (at <c95265f74fdf4905bfb0d5a4b652216c>:0)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].TryGetValue (TKey key, TValue& value) (at <c95265f74fdf4905bfb0d5a4b652216c>:0)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext, System.Exception exception) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/ErrorHandler/ErrorHandler.cs:202)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/ErrorHandler/ErrorHandler.cs:78)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/PipelineHandler.cs:57)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/Handlers/CallbackHandler.cs:45)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/PipelineHandler.cs:57)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/Handlers/Signer.cs:38)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/PipelineHandler.cs:57)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/Handlers/CredentialsRetriever.cs:72)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/PipelineHandler.cs:57)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/RetryHandler/RetryHandler.cs:84)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/PipelineHandler.cs:57)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/Handlers/CallbackHandler.cs:45)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/PipelineHandler.cs:57)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointResolver.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/Handlers/EndpointResolver.cs:34)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/PipelineHandler.cs:57)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/Handlers/Marshaller.cs:37)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/PipelineHandler.cs:57)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/Handlers/CallbackHandler.cs:45)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/PipelineHandler.cs:57)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/Handlers/ErrorCallbackHandler.cs:44)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/PipelineHandler.cs:57)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/Handlers/MetricsHandler.cs:40)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/PipelineHandler.cs:57)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/RuntimePipeline.cs:135)
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TRequest,TResponse] (TRequest request, Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.IMarshaller`2[T,R] marshaller, Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/AmazonServiceClient.cs:204)
Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.InitiateAuth (Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.InitiateAuthRequest request) (at <d5265c16c8474ca8b01b52f514c6ef90>:0)
Com.Mmlac.Authentication.LoginUser (System.String username, System.String password) (at Assets/Authentication.cs:40)
AuthenticationTest.Start () (at Assets/AuthenticationTest.cs:20)
```

Prerequists are to:

- add the Unity AWS-SDK,
- and importantly, add the missing CognitoIdentityProvider:

  - described here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/534
  - ..which links to a possible solution, here:
    https://github.com/SolidWhiteSven/amazon-cognito-unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might find [AWSSDK.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication) useful, it augments the AWS SDK for .NET which is quite limited in the area of AWS Cognito and authentication. Specifically that library handles the SRP protocol, which was something developers ended up coding themselves in a few projects I've seen on GitHub.

There's a good introduction to this library in an Amazon blog post [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cognitoauthentication-extension-library-developer-preview/)

Comment: I tried adding the DLLs from the Extension to the Unity project, replacing any old DLLs as imported from: https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-unity-sdk/latest/aws-unity-sdk-v3-preview.zip

There are problems. It appears the ASWSDK.Extensions are not Unity friendly.